# Someone using our site on robots.txt

Tags: magento, web, directory, robots.txt

Some weeks ago, we discovered someone going on our site with the robots.txt directory:
http://www.ourdomain.com/robots.txt 
I've been doing some research and it said that robots.txt makes the permissions of our search engine?
I'm not certain of that... 
The reason why I'm asking this is because he is trying to get into that file once again today...
The thing is that we do not have this file on our website... So why is someone trying to access that file? Is it dangerous? Should we be worried?
We have tracked the IP address and it says the location is in Texas, and some weeks ago, it was in Venezuela... Is he using a VPN? Is this a bot?

Can someone explain what this file does and why he is trying to access it?

Comment: robots.txt is a file you should have on your server. It tells searchengines where they should and should not look for indexable content. It is probably not a 'he', but an 'it' accessing that file (a searchengine). Read more about it here: http://www.webconfs.com/what-is-robots-txt-article-12.php

Comment: robots.txt is not a secret file, as Richard says it is the first file a search engine visits when it starts to crawl your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a robots.txt (a simple text file) you can specify which URLs of your site should not be crawled by bots (like search engine crawlers).

The location of this file is fixed so that bots always know where to find the rules: the file named `robots.txt` has to be placed in the document root of your host. For example, when your site is `http://example.com/blog`, the robots.txt must be accessible from `http://example.com/robots.txt`.

Polite bots will always check this file before trying to access your pages; impolite bots will ignore it.

If you don’t provide a robots.txt, polite bots assume that they are allowed to crawl everything. To get rid of the 404s, use this robots.txt (which says the same: all bots are allowed to crawl everything):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: Thanks for the widely explained answer!